# No overloaded function takes 2 arguments error with boost::assign::list_of

Tags: c++, boost

Why does this give the error: `Test::Test: no overloaded function takes 2 arguments`

```
class Test
{
public:
    Test(const std::vector<int>&)
    {
    }
};

Test test(boost::assign::list_of(4));
```

Comment: Not sure why, but a fix is `Test test( std::vector<int>(boost::assign::list_of(4)) );`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The implementation of boost::assign::list_of requires the container type, in this case your Test class, to have a two argument constructor that takes a first and last iterator (aka range) to initialize the container with.

Specifically, the error comes from the line below with return Container in the convert metho of the boost::assign_detail::converter class:

```
    template< class Container >
    Container convert( const Container*, default_type_tag ) const
    {
        return Container( begin(), end() );
    }
```

The reason hmjd's workaround is successful is that std::vector has a constructor takes two iterators.